# Heatmap con distintos niveles en el eje con GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo unos datos dispuestos de la siguiente manera: [image: Tabla]

Y estoy intentando generar un heatmap (extender algo que ya he hecho con `geom_raster()`) para poder obtener algo así, con dos niveles en uno de los ejes:

[image: heatmap]

He encontrado una respuesta para el caso de un gráfico de barras (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables), pero un mi caso no funciona.

Espero que alguien me pueda orientar. Gracias!